# How can I achieve this regex without a look ahead assertion?

Tags: javascript, regex, match, regex-lookarounds, capturing-group

I have regex which uses a look ahead assertion to match strings of the format {{ x }}. The regex is `/(?<=\{\{\s)[^}\s]+(?=\s*\}\})/gm`

How can I achieve this without using a look ahead assertion?

Comment: Why not simply use `\{\{\s*([^}\s]+)\s*\}\}` (capturing the part you want instead of using lookarounds to exclude the parts you don't want)? (I've also replaced `\s` with `\s*` for consistency of the opening `{{` with the closing `}}`).

Answer (score 2):

A regex like [`/\{\{\s*([^}]+?)\s*\}\}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/uPFdrO/1) which does match more loose variants of the OP's `{{ x }}`-pattern by making use of ...

- [capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) for targeting every character which is not a closing curly brace except of (optional) leading and trailing whitespace (sequences) ... and a ...
- [lazy (non greedy) quantifier](https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy#lazy-mode) for the pattern's termination of an optional whitespace (sequence) followed by two closing curly braces ... applied via ...
- [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) and an additional [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping task ...

... does the trick.

```js
const sampleDate =
`{{1}} {{}} {{  24 56 48 }}
   {{   245648}}{{ 123  }}`;

console.log(
  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/uPFdrO/1]

  [...sampleDate.matchAll(/\{\{\s*([^}]+?)\s*\}\}/g)]
    .map(([match, capture]) => capture)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

And altering the capturing pattern from `[^}]` to `[^}\s]` does enforce captures which do not contain any space characters. The lazy quantifier then can be dropped as well ...

```js
const sampleDate =
`{{1}} {{}} {{  24 56 48 }}
   {{   245648}}{{ 123  }}`;

console.log(
  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/uPFdrO/2]

  [...sampleDate.matchAll(/\{\{\s*([^}\s]+)\s*\}\}/g)]
    .map(([match, capture]) => capture)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answers, if you want a list of all "x values", you can produce one by repeatedly evaluating `m[1]`, which is the first group, where `m` is one of the matches.

The following variants with and without lookaround are equivalent:

```js
/* With lookaround */
const s = "{{ 1 }}{{ 2 }}";
console.log(s.match(/(?<=\{\{\s*)[^}\s]+(?=\s*\}\})/gm));
/* Without lookaround */
for (var matches = [], m, regex = /\{\{\s*([^}\s]+)\s*\}\}/gm; m = regex.exec(s);)
  matches.push(m[1]);
console.log(matches);
```

The question remains, however: Why do you want to avoid lookarounds?

Comment: It's not supported in Safari < 16.4

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
\{\{\s([^}\s]+)\s*\}\}
```

Your result will be inside the first **group** (the rules inside `()`)